# Confusion concerning joint probability function

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

In the course notes I am studying, the author comments that the joint distribution function $F_{X,Y}$ completely determines the stochastic vector $(X,Y)$ and then proceeds to calculate the following probability:

$P((X,Y) \in \: ]a_1, b_1] \times ]a_2, b_2]) = F_{X,Y}(b_1, b_2) - F_{X,Y}(b_1, a_2) - F_{X,Y}(a_1, b_2) + F_{X,Y}(a_1, a_2)$.

As I understand it, $P((X,Y) \in \: ]a_1, b_1] \times ]a_2, b_2])$ equals $P(a_1 \leq X < b_1, a_2 \leq Y < b_2)$. I can see this clearly in the continuous case, but how to achieve the computation in the general case above is not clear to me.

Comment: I would have thought $P((X,Y) \in \: ]a_1, b_1] \times [a_2, b_2[)$ would mean $P(a_1 \lt X \leq b_1, a_2 \leq Y \lt b_2)$

Comment: My apologies. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: Think that $F$ is a double integral. Sketch in a piece of paper how you would integrate over the square.

Comment: I probably didn't make it sufficiently clear, but I can indeed derive the result when $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables. But in the computation that is given, $X$ and $Y$ can be either discrete, continuous or mixed. I really want to know how to do this precisely in the general case (alas, no details of the computation were given in the course notes!).

Comment: It is still an "integral". Recall that integrals are sums as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that for a probability measure $P$ and measurable sets $A \subset B$ you have $P(B \setminus A) = P (B) - P(A)$. In particular, this means:

$P((X, Y) \in (a_1, b_1] \times (a_2, b_2]) = P(\{X \le b_1 \wedge a_2 < Y \le b_2\} \setminus \{X \le a_1 \wedge a_2 < Y \le b_2\})\\
= P(X \le b_1 \wedge a_2 < Y \le b_2) - P(X \le a_1 \wedge a_2 < Y \le b_2)\\
= (P(X \le b_1 \wedge Y \le b_2) - P(X \le b_1 \wedge Y \le a_2)) - (P(X \le a_1 \wedge Y \le b_2) - P(X \le a_1 \wedge Y \le a_2))$